# Find DLL name of code calling a function C#

Tags: c#, dll, reflection

In a framework library, which is included in all of our projects, we have a Log function.

In the framework

```
public static class Log
{
   GenericLog(string msg){ string caller = GETDLLNAME //implementation}
   GenericError(string msg){ string caller = GETDLLNAME //implementation}
}
```

In other code

```
using Framework;

public class foo
{
    public string GenerateBar()
    {
         Log.GenericLog("FooBar");
    }
}
```

Is there any way to determine the name of the DLL from where Log.GenericLog is called ?

Comment: exception object return all the information, from where the error generated, You can use stack trace to show full description of error

Comment: `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().CodeBase` ?

Comment: I think, the requirements you desire could be solved with the [Assembly Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.reflection.assembly.getentryassembly(v=vs.110).aspx). Have a look at this method specificly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly(v=vs.110).aspx

The Assembly-Class will have all you need.